# Eliminate redundant sub-goals generated by case analysis in Coq

Tags: coq

With a simple definition

```
Inductive B := bb.
Inductive C := cc.

Inductive A :=
 | mkA1 : B -> A
 | mkA2 : C -> A.

Definition id (a: A) : A :=
 match a with 
  | mkA1 b => mkA1 b 
  | mkA2 c => mkA2 c
end.
```

I try to do proofs by case analysis (destruct), something like:

```
Theorem Foo :
  forall  a1 a2 : A , a1 <> a2 -> id a1 <> id a2.
Proof.
 destruct a1; destruct a2.
 Abort.
```

Unsurprisingly, the current prove state contains two equivalent sub-goals:

```
b: B
c: C
______________________________________(2/4)
mkA1 b <> mkA2 c -> id (mkA1 b) <> id (mkA2 c)
______________________________________(3/4)
mkA2 c <> mkA1 b -> id (mkA2 c) <> id (mkA1 b)
```

It seems to me that duplicated sub-goals are quite often when doing structural case analysis. Is there some common way to remove these duplicates?

What I did is to massage the second sub-goal to look like the third:

```
Focus 2; 
intro; apply not_eq_sym in H; apply not_eq_sym; revert H;
Unfocus.
```

Although I still have no way to ask Coq to remove the duplicates. Now I can prove a lemma for my second sub-goal, and reuse it in my third sub-goal. But I would like to know some alternatives.

Comment: Zheng, your example is a bit tricky as indeed the goal is not provable, in this case other than factoring thou an intermediate lemma there is little more that can be done. However, in real use cases one tends to get rid of such redundant steps by using controlled amounts of automation. If you post a specific example we could try to have a look.

Comment: @ejgallego thank you. Can you be specific about `such redundant steps`? do you mean the extraction of lemma is redundant step? or the step of generating redundant sub-goals? or both? or something else? I agree automation with tactics like `abstract` could help with the first case, but if you mean with some proof engineering we do not even need to generate redundant sub-goals at the first place, that's even better!

Comment: Indeed what I mean is that usually such "redundant" subgoals are better get rid of just after their generation.

Comment: @ejgallego without dramatically change the question, I updated to make it trivially provable. Do you think we can apply some controlled amounts of automation on it? or could you shed some lights on where I can get more information about this automation technique? then I ll update the question accordingly? thank you.

Comment: Well, in the question as is now, `now destruct a1; destruct a2.` will solve all the goals.

Comment: `now` is what I call a "controlled" amount of automation, [however I normally use a custom version of ssreflect's `by` ]

Comment: A typical more interesting example is when proving goals such as `forall x y, x = y  -> x == y`, in those cases, you will often call `congruence` to clear up goals that have as hypothesis `A = B` etc... and are otherwise symmetrical.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is some tactic automation that de-duplicates subgoals.  Note that not only must the goals match exactly, but the ordering of the contexts must also match.  You also need to run the initialization tactic before you do case analysis.  This is code for Coq >= 8.5.

```
Inductive B := bb.
Inductive C := cc.

Inductive A :=
| mkA1 : B -> A
| mkA2 : C -> A.

Definition id (a: A) : A :=
  match a with
  | mkA1 b => mkA1 b
  | mkA2 c => mkA2 c
  end.

Record duplicate_prod (A B : Type) := duplicate_conj { duplicate_fst : A ; duplicate_snd : B }.
Definition HERE := True.

Ltac start_remove_duplicates H :=
  simple refine (let H___duplicates := @duplicate_conj _ _ I _ in _);
  [ shelve | | ]; cycle 1.
Ltac find_dup H G :=
  lazymatch type of H with
  | duplicate_prod G _ => constr:(@duplicate_fst _ _ H)
  | duplicate_prod _ _ => find_dup (@duplicate_snd _ _ H) G
  end.
Ltac find_end H :=
  lazymatch type of H with
  | duplicate_prod _ _ => find_end (@duplicate_snd _ _ H)
  | _ => H
  end.
Ltac revert_until H :=
  repeat lazymatch goal with
         | [ H' : _ |- _ ]
           => first [ constr_eq H H'; fail 1
                    | revert H' ]
         end.
Ltac remove_duplicates :=
  [ > lazymatch goal with
      | [ |- duplicate_prod _ _ ] => idtac
      | [ H : duplicate_prod _ _ |- _ ]
        => generalize (I : HERE);
           revert_until H;
           let G := match goal with |- ?G => G end in
           lazymatch type of H with
           | context[duplicate_prod G]
             => let lem := find_dup H G in exact lem
           | _ => let lem := find_end H in
                  refine (@duplicate_fst _ _ lem); clear H; (* clear to work around a bug in Coq *)
                  shelve
           end
      end.. ].
Ltac finish_duplicates :=
  [ > lazymatch goal with
      | [ H : duplicate_prod _ _ |- _ ] => clear H
      end..
  | repeat match goal with
           | [ |- duplicate_prod _ ?e ]
             => split;
                [ repeat lazymatch goal with
                         | [ |- HERE -> _ ] => fail
                         | _ => intro
                         end;
                  intros _
                | try (is_evar e; exact I) ]
           end ].


Theorem Foo :
  forall  a1 a2 : A , a1 <> a2 -> id a1 <> id a2.
Proof.
  start_remove_duplicates.
  destruct a1; destruct a2.
  2:intro; apply not_eq_sym in H; apply not_eq_sym; revert c b H; intros c b.
  all:remove_duplicates.
  all:finish_duplicates.
```

The idea is that you first create an evar that will hold the solutions to unique goals.  Then you do the case analysis.  Then you go through the goals, and solve them either with a fresh projection from the evar, or, if you see that there's already a solution to the goal you're looking at, you use that solution.  Finally, you split up the evar into multiple (deduplicated) goals.  There's some additional boilerplate around reverting hypotheses that didn't exist when you created the evar (necessary to appease variable scoping for well-typed terms), remembering which things came from the context originally, and reintroducing those things back into the context at the end.