# Proof automation

Tags: automation, coq, proof

Assuming having a list of sub-goals by applying tactic `T`:

```
______________________________________(1/10)
A
______________________________________(2/10)
A'
______________________________________(3/10)
A''
```

And assuming we know that Lemma `L` can be used to prove `A` and `A''` but **not** `A'`.

My question is can we sequencing `T` with application result of `L`, which left me with just one sub-goal `A'`?

I tried `T;apply L.` without success, since sequencing seems require all branches/sub-goals proved.

I also tried controlled automation by using `by T;apply L.` from SSReflect, which suggested by this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45264991/eliminate-redundant-sub-goals-generated-by-case-analysis-in-coq). Unfortunately, Coq also get stuck, and report `Ltac calls to ... last call failed.`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the `try` tactical, like this:

```
T; try by apply L.
```

This does the following. First, it applies `T`. Then, on each sub goal, it applies the tactic `by apply L`. If the tactic succeeds, good. Otherwise, if it fails, `try` does nothing.

Answer (score 4):

I would recommend the `T; try by apply L.` from Arthur. But if you need more control, you can use

```
T; [ (* first goal *) now apply L 
   | (* second goal *) now apply L 
   | (* last goal *) idtac ].
```

Answer (score 4):

Coq 8.6 also has goal selectors, so if T creates 4 subgoals you can write

```
T. 1-2,4: apply L.
```

to do apply L in all but the third subgoal.

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned by Vilhelm, Coq 8.6 has goal selectors.

You can also do `T; only 1,3: apply L.` which has the advantage of numbering only the subgoals that were generated by the tactic `T`.

See https://coq.inria.fr/refman/proof-engine/ltac.html#goal-selectors